# Issue creating AWS Amplify Project in Windows

Tags: windows, reactjs, cmd, aws-amplify

I'm attempting to build a simple React application using AWS Amplify. I can't find anything to explain what values should be put into the following fields when running amplify `init`:

```
? Source Directory Path:  src
? Distribution Directory Path: build
? Build Command:  npm.cmd run-script build
? Start Command: npm.cmd run-script start
```

For the path fields (source and build) I tried just putting in the directory that I used for my create-app, but it fails during amplify init with this error:

> Error: X:\Amplify\myAmplifyProject\x:\amplify\myamplifyproject contains invalid WIN32 path characters.

So does anyone know what are the correct values / relevent values to add for the 4 fields shown above?

Answer (score 0):

When I was creating project I was using values like:

```
Source Directory Path:  /
? Distribution Directory Path: build
? Build Command:  npm run-script build
? Start Command: npm run-script start
```

Have you installed amplify-CLI?

I was not using `npm.cmd`, just `npm build` or whatever command is there.